# Highcharts - How to set datalabels format programmatically in Combo chart

Tags: highcharts

I am using combo chart in highcharts. I have two line charts:

1. Having currency values so need $ as prefix
2. Having percentage values so need % as suffix

These chart symbols are dynamic. So I have to add them programmatically. I have added them into axis labels as well as in tooltips. But in data labels it is not applied.

Comment: Please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit our question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.dataLabels.format` parameter to specify how the data labels should looks like. Just add some prefix/suffix to the string `'{point.y}'` definition, here is the code and example how it should be done:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        name: 'Dollars',
        data: [439, 525, 571, 696, 970, 1199, 1371, 1541],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '${point.y}'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Percents',
        data: [434, 525, 571, 696, 970, 1199, 1371, 1541].reverse(),
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.y}%'
        }
    }]
});
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/kxumynL5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.format